# Are these tiny connector pins standard?

Tags: connector, cables, cable-assemblies

I have the following connectors on a [USB dongle](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/CC2540EMK-USB/296-30820-ND/2696222) (the ones on the left of `DEBUG`):

[image]

They are tiny (I put the dongle on an Arduino to show the differences with the typical ones I know)

**Are they standard? And if so - is there a specific name for them which I could use to search a connector?** (I clumsily tried to solder some cables instead but this is out of my soldering league)

Comment: It looks like a pretty standard 0.05" pitch pin header. I use them daily. [These](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/cable-assemblies/rectangular-cable-assemblies/450?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv88=10&pv90=2&pv1119=3&sf=1&FV=ffe001c2&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25) may help ...

Comment: There are also 2mm pitch and 1mm pitch pin headers.

Comment: What is your goal here?  If you read the manual for the TI CC-Debugger programmer that is intended to plug in there, you'll see listed in the package contents "1 x 10-pin flat cable with 2x5 1.27 mm connector".  If you are designing your own *product* consider putting the few signals actually required on something compatible with a spring pin fixture and not just manual cable connection.

Comment: They look like normal "header pins" or "dupont pins" to me. They are pretty standard across electronics like the Arduino, Pi, etc. You can buy male/female ones and cables too - at a low cost. Just search header/dupont cables on eBay or wherever.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I just need to reflash the dongle via an Arduino (https://koenkk.github.io/zigbee2mqtt/information/alternative_flashing_methods.html) and the physical connection is on the way.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the 1.27mm pinheaders, often used for [ARM Cortex SWD](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.faqs/attached/13634/cortex_debug_connectors.pdf) debug connectors. However, this is a TI [CC2531F256](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc2531.pdf) wireless SoC.

Samtec has one with small shroud under sku: [FTSH-105-01-L-DV-K](https://www.samtec.com/products/ftsh-105-01-l-dv-k).

[image]

*(Other vendors also sell parts similar to this, but not with a 3D part tool as Samtec website)*

Comment: Sort of.  It does indeed look like a similar connector.  **But this is not SWD as the MCU pictured has an 8051 core not an ARM core**.  So one might be able to buy a "straight through" cable adapter from the small pitch to a larger one intended for ARM and use that, but something with ARM-specific wiring would probably not work.